# Simulate interactive python session

Tags: python

How can I simulate a python interactive session *using input from a file* and save what would be a transcript? In other words, if I have a file `sample.py`:

```
#
# this is a python script
#
def foo(x,y):
   return x+y

a=1
b=2

c=foo(a,b)

c
```

I want to get `sample.py.out` that looks like this (python banner omitted):

```
>>> #
... # this is a python script
... #
... def foo(x,y):
...    return x+y
... 
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> 
>>> c=foo(a,b)
>>> 
>>> c
3
>>>
```

I've tried feeding stdin to python, twitter's suggestions were 'bash script' with no details (played with the script command in bash, no joy). I feel it should be easy, and I'm missing something simple. Do I need to write a parser using `exec` or something?

Python or ipython solutions would be fine. And I might then want to convert to html and syntax highlight this in a web browser, but that's another problem....

Comment: Are you trying to save your interactive python shells's session to a file or emulate the python shell/console?

Comment: @JamesMills I think OP wants exactly opposite, a script to be converted to look like from interactive shell.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-programoutput/ <-- This will do something like that.

Comment: yeah, slight clarification added. get input from a file, make it look like it was typed. For my example I actually cut n paste into a running python.

Comment: @JamesMills are you sure? As far as I can tell, that extension just runs an external command and inserts the complete output (STDOUT) into the docs. I fail to see how that would work to emulate an interactive interpreter reading and evaluating the source line by line.

Comment: I've used it or something similar before ti similar an interactive python shell as part of documentation with sphinx. So yes I'm sure.

Comment: @JamesMills so what would an example use of the `command-output` or `program-output` directive look like? Emulating a shell session, with several oneline commands that terminate - sure. But I can't see how this could emulate an interactive Python session.

Comment: See: http://mio-lang.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: And I'm sorry the actual ext I used was: https://github.com/thewtex/sphinx-contrib/blob/master/autorun/README -- I wasn't sure which I had used. Sorry :)

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that `.. runblock::` directive in the `program-output` extension ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `code.interact` would work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import code
import fileinput


def show(input):
    lines = iter(input)

    def readline(prompt):
        try:
            command = next(lines).rstrip('\n')
        except StopIteration:
            raise EOFError()
        print(prompt, command, sep='')
        return command

    code.interact(readfunc=readline)


if __name__=="__main__":
    show(fileinput.input())
```

(I updated the code to use `fileinput` so that it reads from either `stdin` or `sys.argv` and made it run under python 2 and 3.)

Comment: Does what it says on the tin. I'm having trouble breaking it :)

Comment: how do I use this? is it from within the python interpreter or bash?  do I enter >>> show(sample.py)

Comment: @Tim save the code as `interact.py` and the input as `sample.py`, then do `python interact.py sample.py`. It will work in py3 when you use the new syntax for `print`.