# simulate coding session in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to simulate a coding session (for video recording session : I am not a touch typist :-)

For example, I have a shell script like this (`test.sh`)

```sh
hello="Hello"
world="world"
echo $hello", "$world
```

And I have a python script like this (`Simulate_KeyPresses.py`) :

```py
import sys
import time
import subprocess

def send_letter(letter):
  # V1 : simple print
  sys.stdout.write(letter)
  sys.stdout.flush()

  # V2: Test with expect (apt-get install expect)
  # cmd = """echo 'send "{}"' | expect""".format(c)
  # subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)


def simulate_keypresses(content):
  lines = content.split("\n")
  for line in lines:
    for c in line:
      send_letter(c)
      time.sleep(0.03)
    send_letter("\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  with open(filename, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
  simulate_keypresses(content)
```

Which I can invoke like this :

```
python Simulate_KeyPresses.py test.sh
```

And it works beautifully.
However when I pipe it to bash, like this:

```
python Simulate_KeyPresses.py test.sh | /bin/bash
```

I get

```
Hello, world
```

i.e I only get stdout and the key presses are not shown.

What I would like to see:

```
hello="Hello"
world="world"
echo $hello", "$world
Hello, world
```

I found a related answer ([Simulate interactive python session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809327/simulate-interactive-python-session)), but it only handle python coding sessions.

I tried to use [Expect](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/), but it does not work as intended (does not show stdin also).

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the program `tee` as:

```
python Simulate_KeyPresses.py test.sh | tee /dev/tty | /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to your script:

```
subprocess.call("./{}".format(filename), shell=True)
```

The result will be

```
hello="Hello"
world="world"
echo $hello", "$world

Hello, world
```